# Robot real time control

Tags: arduino, robotic-arm, ros, matlab, real-time

I want to control a arduino based robot in real time , i am confused whether simulink real time control is a better option or Using ROS ??

I am familiar with the simulink , My application is to controlling the robot using controller with time delay .

Can anyone suggest me which way should i go ?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* JasmeetSingh, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, **how to accomplish something, what something is capable of**, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: Simulink can do control, but ROS does not have any inherent control capability. ROS is a framework that standardizes data communication. Please [research ROS](http://www.ros.org/core-components/) and consider how its capabilities applies to your problem. If you continue to have questions about how to do something, or what something is capable of, please join us in [chat]. If you find you have a *specific, answerable question based on a problem you actually face*, then please ask that question!

Comment: The other doubt i had was , I wish to control an arduino based robot through simulink ,For that i have installed simulink - arduino library . In order , to control the robot in real time  do i have to generate the dynamic model of the robot first and then the trajectories(output) will be sent to arduino for real time application ?? and Feedback from the arduino is fed to the system ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ROS is not offering real time(RT) control by default. Specially ROS 1.0, ROS 2.0 is still under development. Though there are many hacky/tweaky ways to let ROS perform in soft RT. I wouldn't recommend it unless you have some maturity in ROS.

Comment: Thank you Sir. I am not familiar with the ROS platform , i wasn't aware of its capabilities .